# Texas Hold'em: Heads up pre-flop probabilities

Tags: texas-hold-em, pre-flop, statistics

Has anyone calculated the probabilities of winning/losing heads up matchups of all combinations of two players preflop hands in Texas Hold'em, and if so, can they provide a reference?

I could write the code for working out the probability of these preflop matchups myself, but I found it's not trivial (flushes complicate things) and if someone has already done this I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/9106/starting-hands-head-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this link, [Holdem preflop matchups](http://www.pokerstove.com/blog/holdem-preflop-matchups/). It's a zip file of all PF matchups in table form I think.

Other than that, use a search engine using the terms "poker" "hand" "matchups", or some other variation with "preflop" and "probability" in there.

Answer (score 3):

[pokerstove](http://www.pokerstove.com/blog/) is the thing you are looking for!

Comment: The project no longer exists. Do you have a new link?

Comment: https://pokerstove.soft32.com/ seems ok, on linux now, so can not check.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple on-line [preflop odds calculator](http://www.cardfight.com/).

Basically Q2 is a boundary hand. Anything "above" that is profitable on the distance.

Comment: as far as I know it is Q7 and not Q2.

Comment: Use pokerstove! Its Q2s or Q7o