# Starting hands head up

Tags: probability, pre-flop

Does anyone have charts for starting hands heads by position up or even order of hands?

I know any Ace and any pair is valuable but I cannot find more specific guidelines.

I found order of hands heads up [here](http://www.jazbo.com/poker/huholdem.html)

```
AA  0.8520371   A4s 0.5903364   K5  0.5331397   96s 0.4742829   85  0.4142753
KK  0.8239568   A7  0.5884120   J9  0.5325120   J2s 0.4737815   64s 0.4133332
QQ  0.7992516   K8s 0.5831235   K2s 0.5321173   Q2  0.4729544   83s 0.4087350
JJ  0.7746947   A3s 0.5822032   Q5s 0.5276941   T5s 0.4721626   94  0.4067105
TT  0.7501178   QJ  0.5813469   T8s 0.5233437   J5  0.4718089   75  0.4051197
99  0.7205725   K9  0.5781192   K4  0.5232747   T4s 0.4653049   82s 0.4027163
88  0.6916304   A5  0.5769653   J7s 0.5232478   97  0.4629781   73s 0.4003594
AKs 0.6704463   A6  0.5768245   Q4s 0.5185530   86s 0.4624327   93  0.4001951
77  0.6623602   Q9s 0.5766432   Q7  0.5176567   J4  0.4618638   65  0.3994430
AQs 0.6620886   K7s 0.5753774   T9  0.5153167   T6  0.4609200   53s 0.3969296
AJs 0.6539268   JTs 0.5752786   J8  0.5149016   95s 0.4572187   63s 0.3953356
AK  0.6532007   A2s 0.5737890   K3  0.5142569   T3s 0.4569251   84  0.3944679
ATs 0.6460239   QT  0.5729078   Q6  0.5102405   76s 0.4537177   92  0.3909794
AQ  0.6443184   44  0.5702282   Q3s 0.5101925   J3  0.4527554   43s 0.3864195
AJ  0.6356326   A4  0.5672968   98s 0.5080076   87  0.4505081   74  0.3854983
KQs 0.6340040   K6s 0.5664074   T7s 0.5063904   T2s 0.4483948   72s 0.3815589
66  0.6328475   K8  0.5602017   J6s 0.5060591   85s 0.4454499   54  0.3815529
A9s 0.6278121   Q8s 0.5601773   K2  0.5050872   96  0.4449135   64  0.3801049
AT  0.6272165   A3  0.5584460   22  0.5033402   J2  0.4434847   52s 0.3784933
KJs 0.6256734   K5s 0.5579292   Q2s 0.5016904   T5  0.4425095   62s 0.3766896
A8s 0.6194381   J9s 0.5566247   Q5  0.5012008   94s 0.4386197   83  0.3748381
KTs 0.6178856   Q9  0.5536043   J5s 0.4998685   75s 0.4367554   42s 0.3682901
KQ  0.6145580   JT  0.5524770   T8  0.4972127   T4  0.4350411   82  0.3682767
A7s 0.6098396   K7  0.5518735   J7  0.4968193   93s 0.4326426   73  0.3660226
A9  0.6077281   A2  0.5492856   Q4  0.4912768   86  0.4324090   53  0.3626477
KJ  0.6056869   K4s 0.5488464   97s 0.4911773   65s 0.4313339   63  0.3607763
55  0.6032492   Q7s 0.5430226   J4s 0.4907045   84s 0.4270163   32s 0.3598443
QJs 0.6025921   K6  0.5422328   T6s 0.4894068   95  0.4266914   43  0.3514589
K9s 0.5998848   K3s 0.5405498   J3s 0.4823162   T3  0.4259455   72  0.3458365
A5s 0.5992293   T9s 0.5402753   Q3  0.4821944   92s 0.4241517   52  0.3428465
A6s 0.5990583   J8s 0.5401564   98  0.4809703   76  0.4232275   62  0.3407514
A8  0.5987261   33  0.5369308   87s 0.4793634   74s 0.4184931   42  0.3319975
KT  0.5973892   Q6s 0.5361257   T7  0.4790814   T2  0.4166835   32  0.3230323
QTs 0.5946756   Q8  0.5359979   J6  0.4784427   54s 0.4145342
```

Comment: I'd argue that charts are not a great idea in general, because they don't take account for other factors. I can find some charts on heads-up for you, but they're not modern/up to date so I'm not sure how representative of the modern game they would be. As a general piece of advice, on the button you want to open or call any pairs, any suited connector, any unsuited connectors from like 89+. From the BB you can cut out the lower Aces(little tight though) and the unsuited connectors like 89,  and cut out the lower suited connectors. I can expand a bit on this if you want me to.

Comment: @Grinch91 Might as well is will be better than my answer

Comment: I'll see if I can dig out some charts later for you then :)

Comment: @Grinch91 You are a mod?

Comment: Yup, I sure am! Also I had forgot to post on this in the past, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I am a regular poker player and I play poker tournaments almost every day.
Also I have a big heads up experience.
I read 3 poker books including Mathematics of Poker and Intelligent Poker Player.

In headsd-up it is recommended to open raise from Small Blind with 70% of hands. You can learn best 70% of hands downloading free popular poker calculator Equilab. As you are a beginner 70% may seem too many for you. But it is so because when you are a Small Blind in heads up you will be in position at postflop. Playing postflop in position is more profitable.

There are no well known static preflop ranges for heads up that became a standard.

Personally I like to open raise from SB no limit heads up with 60% of hands:
22+,A2s+,K2s+,Q2s+,J2s+,T3s+,95s+,85s+,75s+,64s+,54s,A2o+,K2o+,Q5o+,J7o+,T7o+,97o+,87o

And I raise not to 2BB but to 2.5 or 3BB. It is not new and many players plays approximately so. It is normal to call open raise of SB from BB with 65% of hands. Calling from BB should be tighter than SB raises. I call with 55% of hands: 33+,A2s+,K2s+,Q2s+,J3s+,T5s+,95s+,85s+,75s+,65s,A2o+,K4o+,Q6o+,J7o+,T7o+,97o+,87o

The range for 3BET from BB positoin is different almost for any player. It is normal to 3Bet with 25-10% of hands. Sometimes it is better not to 3BET with AA, KK, QQ. Many heads up players does not 3Bet at all.

I suppose you are interested in the most popular no limit mode. There are in internet precalculted push/fold charts for heads up and not only heads up. How to play with all-in in a late trounament stage when effective stacks are less than 12BB. I know 2 commercial applications for calculating perfect preflop push/fold range tables: Holdem Resource Calculator and Icmizer 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am just sort of guessing here.  I won't accept my own answer here.

Because of the blinds you need to be playing most of the hands

If the BB is playing 3/4 that is through 65s on that list and kind of makes sense.

SB it depends on betting from BB.

The power of suited connectors goes down but they come in based on the number of hands you need to play.